# How to use .env in Flutter web?

Tags: flutter, dart, environment-variables

**Short story:**

I am trying to use `.env` file in my Flutter Web project.

I used `flutter_dotenv` before in Flutter mobile app but it is not working in Flutter web.

How can we use .env file in Flutter web?

**Long Story:**

For now, I am using dart file to save current constant values such as backend url.

Backend is in same domain like this => `https://domain_for_webapp.com/api/`

```
class Environment {

  // API URL
  static const String API_URL ='https://domain_for_webapp.com/api/';
...
```

But problem here is I have **one more** server to deploy same site `https://another_domain_for_webapp.com/api/`
So I tried to solve that by using relative url

```
class Environment {

  // API URL
  static const String API_URL ='/api/';
...
```

But Flutter web can't find correct full API url for each server.

To solve this I have been trying to use `.env` like in normal web app.

But I can't use `.env` in Flutter web.

Is there any proper solution for this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like mentioned [here](https://github.com/java-james/flutter_dotenv/issues/28), you can rename your .env file to something that doesn't start with a dot. I've changed my .env file to "dotenv".

Answer (score 17):

Unfortunately, .env doesn't seem to work with web as you've noticed. Hopefully it'll get integrated eventually, but for now when I had the same issue I found that the recommended way of configuring the web involves using environment variables and the `dart-define` parameter:

```dart
String urlBase = const String.fromEnvironment("url_base");
```

This way you can set up your run and build environment with different variables.

Unfortunately, this isn't quite as 'set and forget' as a .env file, so I like to put a guard like this on it so that you're made aware of it immediately when you try running:

```dart
if (urlBase == null) {
  throw Exception("You must define url_base. This can be done "
                  "with the --dart-define arg to run or build");
}
```

If you're using an IDE you will need to pass in the parameters. For Visual Studio Code you can do this with a `launch.json` file something like this:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Flutter",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "dart",
        "args": [
            "--dart-define",
            "url_base=https://myurl.com/base"
        ]
    }
]
```

And for IntelliJ/Android Studio you can do it in the run configuration:

[image: IntelliJ run configuration]

In whatever you use for your build tooling, it's as simple as adding the additional parameter to the `flutter build web` command, i.e. with docker:

```
RUN /usr/local/flutter/bin/flutter build web --dart-define url_base=$url_base
```

Comment: Thank you. Seems this is the best solution for now.
I hope we can use `.env` soon!

Comment: Is there any way to access the dart-define variables inside the index.html file?

Comment: @JoseTapizquent I don't think so - that gets built into the generated .js file upon build

Answer (score 0):

[This Article](https://www.schibsted.pl/blog/flutter-of-many-flavors/) talks about creating environment for Flutter on the web.
Using the
`flutter run --dart-define=<VARIABLE>` command.
.